# How to add a JButton Button to the view

Tags: java, swing, awt

This is a minimalist example of my problem so, please do not tell me that the class is useless and that I can do it with only a JPannel in my main class. Thanks.

How do I add a `JButton` with text in the `EcranAcceuil` class below?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class jeu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        // debut definition fenetre    
        JFrame fenetrejeu = new JFrame();    
        fenetrejeu.setTitle("QUEST");
        fenetrejeu.setSize(1000, 1000);
        fenetrejeu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        fenetrejeu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fenetrejeu.setContentPane(new EcranAcceuil());
        fenetrejeu.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**EcranAcceuil**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class EcranAcceuil extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: "pls don't tell me that the class is useless..." test cases are accepted and appreciated. Do you really want to be doing custom painting on a class that has components as members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class EcranAcceuil extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JButton btnHello;
    JTextField txtHello;

    EcranAcceuil() {
        btnHello = new JButton("Hello");
        btnHello.addActionListener(this);
        txtHello = new JTextField(20);
        add(txtHello);
        add(btnHello);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        txtHello.setText("Hello");
    }
}

public class jeu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // debut definition fenetre
        JFrame fenetrejeu = new JFrame();
        fenetrejeu.setTitle("QUEST");
        fenetrejeu.setSize(1000, 1000);
        fenetrejeu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        fenetrejeu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fenetrejeu.setContentPane(new EcranAcceuil());
        fenetrejeu.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I also recommend you follow [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. `class jeu` should be `class Jeu`.

Comment: And where can I put the Listener?

Comment: @starter45 - I've updated my code to incorporate this requirement.

Comment: Your paintComponent override should include a call to super.paintComponent. as well as @Override annotation.

Comment: Thanks, @GilbertLeBlanc for the suggestion. I've updated the answer to incorporate it.